# The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'int' how can i fix it?

Tags: flutter

im new to flutter and ive got some issue with my code
how can i fix this problem ?
im stucked with this problem for few days and still cannot fix it

**The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'int'**

> Here's my error part

```
Services.updateEmployee(
        employee.id, _firstNameController.text, _lastNameController.text)
    .then((result) {
  if ('success' == result) {
    _getEmployees(); // Refresh the list after update
    setState(() {
      _isUpdating = false;
    });
```

> Here's the method

```
_updateEmployee(Employee employee) {
setState(() {
  _isUpdating = true;
});
_showProgress('Updating Employee...');

Services.updateEmployee(
        employee.id, _firstNameController.text, _lastNameController.text)
    .then((result) {
  if ('success' == result) {
    _getEmployees(); // Refresh the list after update
    setState(() {
      _isUpdating = false;
    });
    _clearValues();
  }
});
```

Comment: Can you include your method as well. I think you just need to typecast, like `employee.id.toString()`

Comment: On your second code snippet you have `Services.updateEmployee(employee.id.toString(),` Should this not just be `Services.updateEmployee(employee.id,`??

Comment: ive already trying to add toString() to my problem, and it still not fix

Answer (score 0):

Your method is looking for an `int` but you are passing a `String`, that's why it's giving you an error.

Example:

```
// Doesn't give you an error
testMethod(1);

// Gives you an error (The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'int')
testMethod("1");

void testMethod(int empId) {
  print(empId);
}
```

Hope this helped to fix your error.

Comment: im sorry i still not get it, im really a beginner to coding stuff

Comment: can i see your Services.updateEmployee()  method?

Comment: ive already add my method on the post, thanks before

Comment: Services.updateEmployee(Employee employee ) takes Employee object as a parameter?